# spring-boot actuator endpoint values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am wondering if anyone can shed some light onto where the values are coming from in the spring-boot actuator endpoints such as `/health` or `/metrics`. Under `/health` it displays diskSpace as

```
diskSpace :  {
     status: UP
     total : 983430832128
     free  : 915480453120
}
```

where are these values coming from? My personal machine? I am confused because these values would make sense (assuming its a measurement in bytes) as this is how much local diskspace I have. However under `/metrics` it shows

```
mem: 319858
```

which is nowhere near the amount of memory my machine has, but again under `/metrics` the load average is the same as my machine (roughly)

Comment: Mem is the amount of java memory used and available not the physical amount in your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm assuming then the rest of my assumptions are correct then?

Comment: Well, it depends... It might be correct depending on what you run. If you are running a vm or docker the values might represent something different (or be off due to the virtualization). Although I guess most of those issues have been fixed in newer java versions (cpu count, etc.) you might run into that. But generally yes your assumptions are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have rightly guessed

```
diskSpace :  {
     status: UP
     total : 983430832128
     free  : 915480453120
}
```

Indicates total and free space in your local machine.  This is coming from `DiskSpaceHealthIndicator`. Search for this class and look at the code.  Here is the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/system/DiskSpaceHealthIndicator.java). And yes, it is in bytes.

```
mem: 319858
```

This is from `/metrics`. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

> Shows ‘metrics’ information for the current application.

In this case application means the jvm. So it is the memory you allocated (or by default assumed) when jvm was started.